# is it possible to format string in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a new pandas user and I would like to ask is it possible to do this?

Here is the sample of my data frame. all data type of both attributes are the string.

```
id class
A1  X1,41
A1  X1,42
A1  X1,43
A2  X1,41
A2  X1,45
```

I have merged the data frame using groupby and the results are being like this. `df = df.groupby(['id']).sum()`

```
id class
A1 X1,41X1,42X1,43
A2 X1,41X1,45
```

but I would like the results to be like this (hope the data contains in the form of list.)

```
id class
A1 [X1,41], [X1,42], [X1,43]
A2 [X1,41], [X1,45]
```

Comment: It's possible, but not recommended. Pandas is not designed to hold lists in series. If you're concerned about memory / performance, looking at [Categorical Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) is a **much** better idea.

Comment: The things you have in the original `class` column are strings.  Not lists!  It looks like from your desired output that you have lists of lists where each nested list only has a single string in it.  That makes very little sense to me.  You need to do a better job of explaining what it is inside your dataframe and what it is you want there when you are done.

Comment: Please edit your post to show how you used `groupby`. Maybe modifying that code a bit can someone answer your question.

Comment: thank you for all comments, i have edited the post

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: [[_x] for _x in x['class']])
```

This means to groupby the `'id'` column, and for every grouped object, apply the function given. In this case I provide a function that creates a list of lists of the objects in that groupby object. `_x` could be anything, I just named it that to reflect that it is temporary and a placeholder.

Comment: could you please explain me what does _x mean?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Ethan Koch's answer:

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: [[_x] for _x in x['class']])
```

returns a Series, not a Dataframe. To convert back to Dataframe:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'id':df.index, 'class':df.values})
```